# MovableObject java syntax error

Tags: java

I have a class Tile that handles position of the objects. The compiler doesn't have any problems with that class.

However, when I try to use that class in MovableObject, I can't use the methods when I create a new Tile.

Here is my code:

```
package game;

public class Tile {
    int posx;
    int posy;
    int indice;
    Tile [] proximasSalidas;
    //int fila;
    //int columna;
    public boolean esInterseccion;
    boolean esPasillo;
    boolean esL;
    Tile [] adyacencias;

    public Tile(){
        posx = 0;
        posy = 0;
        proximasSalidas = null;
        esInterseccion = false;
        esPasillo = false;
        esL = false;
        adyacencias = null;
    }

    public Tile(int posx,int posy,Tile [] adyacencias,Tile [] proximasSalidas,boolean esPasillo, boolean esInterseccion, boolean esL){
        this.posx = posx;
        this.posy = posy;
        this.proximasSalidas = proximasSalidas;
        this.adyacencias = adyacencias;
        this.esInterseccion = esInterseccion;
        this.esPasillo = esPasillo;
        this.esL = esL;
    }

    public void setValores(int posx,int posy,Tile [] adyacencias,Tile [] proximasSalidas,boolean esPasillo, boolean esInterseccion, boolean esL){
        this.posx = posx;
        this.posy = posy;
        this.proximasSalidas = proximasSalidas;
        this.adyacencias = adyacencias;
        this.esInterseccion = esInterseccion;
        this.esPasillo = esPasillo;
        this.esL = esL;
    }



}
```

And my MovableObject class:

```
package game;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import com.golden.gamedev.*;
import com.golden.gamedev.*;
import com.golden.gamedev.engine.*;
import com.golden.gamedev.object.*;
import com.golden.gamedev.object.sprite.*;
import com.golden.gamedev.engine.BaseAudioRenderer;

public  class MovableObject {

    public int columna;
    public int fila;
    public int pos_x;
    public int pos_y;
    private int moveSize;
    public int direction;
    public int[] availableDirections;
    public int targetTile;


    Tile t1 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,false,false,false);//no es pasillo
    Tile t0 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//es pasillo



    //adyacencias,proximasSalidas,es pasillo,es interseccion,esL

    Tile t3 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t4 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t6 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t7 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t10 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t11 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t13 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t14 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t16 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t17 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t18 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t19 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t20 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t21 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t23 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t25 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t27 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t29 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t31 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t33 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t34 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t35 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t36 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t38 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t41 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t43 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t44 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t46 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t48 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t50 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t52 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t53 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t54 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t55 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t57 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t58 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t60 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t61 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t63 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t64 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t66 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t67 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t68 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t69 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t70 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t71 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t72 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t73 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t74 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t75 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t77 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t78 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t80 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t82 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t83 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t85 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t86 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t88 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t90 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t91 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t93 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t94 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t95 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t96 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t97 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t98 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t100 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t101 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t103 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion
    Tile t104 = new Tile(1,1,null,null,true,false,false);//no es interseccion



    Tile t2 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t3,t16},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t8 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t7,t18},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t9 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t19,t10},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t15 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t14,t21},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t37 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t34,t38},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t39 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t38,t43},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t40 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t44,t41},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t42 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t41,t35},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t45 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t46,t60},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t51 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t50,t61},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t99 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t96,t100},null,true,true,true);//es L
    Tile t105 = new Tile(1,1,new Tile[]{t98,t104},null,true,true,true);//es L

    Tile t56 = new Tile();



    t56.setValores(1,1,new Tile[]{t52,t57,t66},new Tile[]{t5,t59,t76},true,true,false);//es interseccion


 ...
```

In the above code, the compiler isn't recognizing `setValores()` (at the bottom of MoveableObject).

Comment: There's a **lot** of code here.  Would you care to share the exception you're receiving, and trim the code sample you've provided to the absolute, bare minimum required?

Comment: Im sorry, but i tought it would be better to share all. Let me edit it.

Comment: Can you be more specific with the exact error you're getting from the compiler? Java compiler messages are generally very useful.

Comment: I think your second class could be shortened dramatically to just create one `Tile` and call `setValores` on it? I assume the problem still happens in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**

It's because your executable code cannot float into the class's body.

The next line has to be located into a class method.

```
 t56.setValores(1,1,new Tile[]{t52,t57,t66},new Tile[]{t5,t59,t76},true,true,false);//es interseccion
```

**Explanation:**

For your chunk of code, it's the first line that does not correspond to just a variable/attribute declaration and it includes some executable code, It's the specific reason why you are getting compilation errors for this specific line and not for any other line before.

**About your approach**

On the other hand , the code will work once you includes this specific line into a method, but this approach does not look as an efficient way to code whatever you are pretending to do.

Comment: I just headdesked because I hadn't noticed that until you pointed it out, and probably would have if I'd tried to compile it myself...